# Enviar Request despues de x segundos

Tags: php, xml, webservice

Buen dia, estoy enviando un request xml a un webservice mediante PHP, lo que necesito es que si han pasado x segundos y no e obtenido respuesta por parte del webservice cancele ese request y me envie otro diferente, como puedo realizarlo?

Saludos!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrar tu codigo actual?

Answer (score 1):

No se cual sea tu proposito, pero
**Usar timeout para solicitar uno u otro request no es tan buena practica, normalmente timeout debe utilizarse para 'cachar' errores de respuesta de los servicios y evitar que tu servidor se quede colgado esperando respuesta**

Si no hay otra opción así puedes lograr lo que quieres:

Puedes usar la [curl para PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) y usar la opción `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` para asignarle un tiempo de respuesta.

Para correr cierto código cuanto el `timeout` acabe debes usar [`curl_errno`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php).

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; //segundos
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch) == 28){ // 28 -> CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT
    //timeout, código para el segundo request
}

curl_close($ch);
```

[PHP Curl](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)

[Curl Errno](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo puedes utilizar esta función **sleep(10);** disponible en php 5.4 a 5.7
 después del envío. quedo atento.

me escribe y seguimos mirando

Comment: Por favor explica por qué esta función lo soluciona y agrega un ejemplo

Comment: te permite esperar un tiempo y ya luego continua ejecutando el bloque de código que continua  public function handle_login() {
    if($uid = user::check_password($_REQUEST['email'], $_REQUEST['password'])) {
        return self::authenticate_user($uid);
    }
    else {
        // delay failed output by 2 seconds
        // to prevent bruit force attacks
        sleep(2);
        return self::login_failed();
    }
}

Comment: pero no es lo que esta preguntando...